# change checkbox attr if first checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I want to show/hide a checkbox by checking if the first checkbox is checked.

Code:

```
$j('#main_share').bind("click", function() {

        if( $j(this).is(':checked') ) {
            //check ext_share box
            $j('#allow_ext_share').attr('checked', true);
            //show ext_share box    
            $j('#ext_share_li').show(); 

        } else {

            //hide ext_share box    
            $j('#ext_share_li').hide(); 
            //uncheck ext_share box
            $j('#allow_ext_share').attr('checked', false); 
        }                       

});
```

When I uncheck the box everthing works as expected, but if I recheck it the checkbox shows again but remains unchecked ??

QUESTION: How do I check the checkbox when it shows again.

Comment: use `.prop()` instead `$j('#allow_ext_share').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use prop instead of attr :

```
$j('#allow_ext_share').prop('checked', true);
//Later
$j('#allow_ext_share').prop('checked', false);
```

Can also reduce the code to that :

```
$j('#main_share').bind("click", function() {
    $j('#allow_ext_share').prop('checked', this.checked); 
    $j('#ext_share_li').toggle(this.checked);   
});
```

Comment: #ext_share_li is actually the <li> containing the checkbox (#allow_ext_share) that I wish to hide/show, but I see what you are trying to do and will make it shorter. ty.

Comment: @maximl337 that is what it is doing, `toggle` is a show/hide function. `this.checked` return a boolean. Passing true to toggle show the element and passing false hide it. Isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `attr` to `prop`

```
$j('#allow_ext_share').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: marking Karl's answer as complete as he answered 14 secs earlier :P.. but thank you.